# IIS not using correct version for .NET Core - how to manage?

Tags: iis, runtime, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm trying to run a locally published application which immediately throws an exception:

## An error occurred while starting the application.

> .NET Core 4.6.26725.06 X86 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version **2.1.1-rtm-30846**    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.16299    |   Need help?

This *leads me to believe* that IIS uses version `2.1.1-rtm-30846` even though I just downloaded the latest `2.1.4` version from the website.

However I can only get information about the `SDK` that is being used by `dotnet`, not the `Runtime`.

[image]

I can get a list of `SDK` versions that are *installed* though using `dotnet --info` (output below). But this also just shows the `2.1.4` version listed.

**How do I manage which version IIS uses for .NET core *runtime*?**

```
.NET Core runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0-preview1-final [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0-rc1-final [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0-preview1-final [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0-rc1-final [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 1.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.5 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.6 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.7 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.0.9 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0-preview1-26216-03 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0-rc1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.1 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.2 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.3 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.4 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

Comment: Read the manifest file in the output folder of `dotnet publish` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore21

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a manifest file. I see there is a `--manifest` argument that can be specified for `dotnet publish`, however this seems to be used as input?

Comment: Or I should say `runtimeconfig.json` https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/12/21/netcore-primitives/#runtimeconfigjson

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to say. I can't find any manifest file in the output folder... It should be possible to run this without `runtimeconfig.json` right?

Comment: For framework dependent deployment, I don't think you can go without `runtimeconfig.json`, as that's what `dotnet` command uses to initialize the environment (aka runtime). That also determines which version of the runtime should be used (thus, IIS is not playing that role).

Comment: But I don't want to make a framework dependent deployment. I'd rather have my environment setup to be able to run this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180941/discussion-between-ropstah-and-lex-li).

Answer (score 0):

This actually doesn't have anything to do with IIS, since IIS simply acts as a reverse proxy. The problem is that the runtime version selection is failing to use the latest installed version of the .NET Core runtime for some reason. You can read more about how this process works [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection), but to summarize:

The latest installed patch version is used, unless...

1. If there is a global.json file specifying a specific version
2. The target framework specified limits the major version. For example, if you're targeting `netcoreapp2.0`, then the latest 2.0 runtime will be used, even if you have 2.1 runtimes installed.
3. The app was deployed as self-contained, in which case, it will always use the runtime it was published with.

First, ensure that you don't have a global.json file specifying a runtime version. This file could exist in the root of your project or any containing directory and still have effect. Next, check the version of .NET Core your project is targeting and ensure it's `netcoreapp2.1`, not `netcoreapp2.0`.

Comment: 1. There is *no* `global.json` file present (*not* in any subdirectory as well). 2. The target framework is set to `netcoreapp2.1`. 3. I tried deploying as self-contained exactly because of this reason **as well**, but this yielded the same exception...

Comment: It gets even more strange, i uninstalled (and manually deleted from %ProgramFiles%\dotnet\shared) all previous `.net core` runtimes (leaving only `2.1.3` and `2.1.4` but for some reason IIS keeps using `2.1.1-rtm-30846`